# Не удается установить пакет из nuget C#

Tags: c#, nuget

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку https://www.nuget.org/packages/YouTubeSearch/2.2.2 из nuget, однако каждый раз ошибка `"Не удалось установить пакет «YouTubeSearch 2.2.2». Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — «.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой."`.

Пробовал разные версии фреймворка, начиная с 2.0 и заканчивая 4.8 и везде все то же самое.
Скачивал пакет как архив и распаковывал, добавить его в проект удается, однако в нем есть зависимость от других библиотек, добавить которые в проект тоже не удается, т.к. появляется та же ошибка.

В чем может быть проблема?
Стоит VS 2015.

Comment: Данный пакет является `.NETStandard 2.0`, он рассчитан больше на кроссплатформенность, а это значит, что он больше нацелен на `.NET Core`. Вы можете посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/net-standard) описание и увидите следующее: `Для проектов .NET Framework, которым нужно использовать такие библиотеки, рекомендуем обновить проект и использовать в качестве целевой версию .NET Framework 4.7.2 или выше.`. То есть я бы на вашем месте использовал бы `.NET Core`, либо `.NET Framework 4.7.2` версии. Кстати, `.NET Standart 2.1` не поддерживает `.NET Framework` вовсе.

Comment: Кстати, что мешает поставить VS 2019 Community?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я переключал на 4.8, сейчас ставил 4.7.2, однако результат тот же. По ссылке, что Вы дали, нашел такое: `Перечисленные версии для .NET Framework применимы к пакету SDK для .NET Core 2.0 и инструментарию более поздних версий. В предыдущих версиях использовалось другое сопоставление для .NET Standard 1.5 и более поздних версий. Если вы не можете обновить Visual Studio до версии 2017 и выше, можно скачать инструментарий для средств .NET Core для Visual Studio 2015`. Это значит, что мне надо установить какую-то из тамошних версий, совместимых с VS 2015?

Comment: @aepot как-то уже привык к 15-ой версии) Да и натыкался на других форумах на темы про ее баги. И раз уж про это зашла речь, мои проекты с VS 15 будут работать в VS 17 или 19?

Comment: Будут работать. Вы попробуйте, делать бэкапы никто не запрещал.